# Unable to add Mixpanel to iOS (ObjectiveC) application

Tags: ios, mobile, 64-bit, mixpanel

I'm trying to add Mixpanel to my iOS app written in ObjectiveC but getting the following error:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Mixpanel", referenced from: objc-class-ref in NEAppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I've tried installing Mixpanel both manually, and though cocoapods. Both methods gave the same result. I'm importing "Mixpanel.h" in my AppDelegate and trying to create an instance of Mixpanel using my token. This causes the build to fail with the error given above.

I've tried adding the x86_64 architecture to the Build Details but that didn't change anything. If I remove the Mixpanel instance call, the app builds fine. Has anyone experienced this before?
Cheers!

Comment: Getting the same error. Did you resolve it?

Comment: I was able to solve this by checking "Import as group" when dragging and dropping into XCode. Try removing whatever you did and start fresh. Make sure you select that option

Comment: Adding Mixpanel using the "Create group" option helped remove the linker error but now I'm seeing an error in `Mixpanel+HostWatchOS.h - 'Mixpanel/Mixpanel.h' file not found`

Comment: Have you downloaded the latest Mixpanel library? You might want to check that file and see if it's missing an #import <Mixpanel/Mixpanel.h> statement at the top.